# How to recover ram from virtualbox to host?

Tags: virtualbox

04 twice on virtualbox, my main machine has 16GB RAM.
I have deleted Ubuntu from virtualbox, and I uninstalled virtualbox too.
My available memory is 13.7GB. Does anyone has any idea why this happened and what can I do?

Comment: Hi I installed Ubuntu 18.04 twice on virtualbox, my main machine has 16GB RAM. I have deleted Ubuntu from virtualbox, and I uninstalled virtualbox too. My available memory is 13.7GB. Does anyone has any idea why this happened and what can I do?

Comment: What is your host OS.  You haven't told us, or if you have - it was unclear as you seemed to imply Ubuntu was installed as a VM which has since been deleted.

Comment: my host OS is Windows 10

Answer (score 2):

Since your host OS is Windows and you're not running any VM's, this is a question about Windows, not Ubuntu. That said, 13.7 GB available doesn't sound abnormal for a machine with 16 GB. The difference between that and 16GB is probably used by the OS and other running software. You may have a couple of browser tabs open.

If you go to the Task Manager and click on More Details on the bottom left and then sort by the memory column you can see which processes are taking up most memory.

Answer (score 2):

I don't think this has anything to do with Ubuntu, or with VirtualBox for that matter. VirtualBox is a "Type 2" hypervisor which means it resides completely within your own operating system. What's more likely is that something else in your system is reserving memory, perhaps an integrated GPU for example. Open the Windows Task Manager, select the "More details" drop down and go to the "Memory" section. check to see if the "Hardware reserved" figure accounts for most of your "missing" RAM.